# which persistant memory is better choice?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

need to save some persistent data. the data would only contain 3 or 4 arrays with 100-200 single value entries.

```
(array) data
(
  (
    (dictionary) key -> value
  )
  (
    (dictionary) key -> value
  (
  //etc
)
```

these are just simple lists to show in pickers.

so far i've used NSUserDefault to store single dictionary values, and i'm wondering if it would suffice for this new data or do i need to consider using Core Data?

at this point in time, i don't see my program needing to sore more data then this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on task.

You should answer on these questions:

1. How often this data should be changed?
2. How often this data should be queried ?
3. What kind of queries do you want to use on this data?

As far as I see, if you just need to show them in pickers, you obviously can use NSUserDefaults, or plist file to save this data between launches.

And NSArray/NSDictionary to use it in app.

Comment: updating would be infrequent and access would be at most once per application run (would load on demand, and this feature would not be used every time).

think i'll just stick with NSUserDefaults rather then learn how to use Core Data, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

NSUserDefaults shouldn't have any trouble with the data usage you described.

That said, it doesn't mean it's the ideal solution.  NSUserDefaults are really intended to deal with user preferences. So, if these values aren't preferences NSUSerDefaults isn't really the place for them. (not that it won't work)

CoreData might be a little overkill for your situation, but it might be worth the intial learning curve to have that skill under your belt.

Another solution would be to simply use NSArray or NSDictionary classes if your data is consistant.

NSUserDefault doc - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

How often is this accessed or changed? I would guess that NSUserDefaults is fine.